# python gzipped fileinput returns binary string instead of text string

Tags: python, string, file-io, python-3.x, gzip

When I loop over the lines of a set of gzipped files with the module fileinput like this:

```
for line in fileinput.FileInput(files=gzipped_files,openhook=fileinput.hook_compressed):
```

Then those lines are byte strings and not text strings.

When using the module gzip this can be prevented by opening the files with 'rt' instead of 'rb': http://bugs.python.org/issue13989

Is there a similar fix for the module fileinput, so I can have it return text strings instead of byte strings? I tried adding mode='rt', but then I get this error:

```
ValueError: FileInput opening mode must be one of 'r', 'rU', 'U' and 'rb'
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You'd have to implement your own `openhook` function to open the files with a codec:

```
import os

def hook_compressed_text(filename, mode, encoding='utf8'):
    ext = os.path.splitext(filename)[1]
    if ext == '.gz':
        import gzip
        return gzip.open(filename, mode + 't', encoding=encoding)
    elif ext == '.bz2':
        import bz2
        return bz2.open(filename, mode + 't', encoding=encoding)
    else:
        return open(filename, mode, encoding=encoding)
```

Comment: Just read http://docs.python.org/3/library/bz2.html after getting ValueError: Invalid mode: 'rt'. To open bz2 compressed file in text (or binary) mode use bz2.open.

Answer (score 3):

Coming a bit late to the party, but wouldn't it be simpler to do this?

```
for line in fileinput.FileInput(files=gzipped_files, openhook=fileinput.hook_compressed):
    if isinstance(line, bytes):
        line = line.decode()
    ...
```

Comment: This is the better answer.  Works very well for handling mixed input from text files and gzipped files.